# How to check Passport isAuthenticated on express.Router()

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Using `passport.js`, what is the recommended way to check if a user `isAuthenticated`?

I see examples of people doing things like this:

```
app.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req,res){});
```

How does this even work, `app.get` only accepts two arguments?

What about when I use `express.Router()`?

What's the correct syntax for `router.get`?

More generally, checking `isAuthenticated` at every route seems inefficient. Is there a better way to check authentication in an Express app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get` accepts as many [middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) as you need. According to the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.METHOD):

> **router.METHOD(path, [callback, ...] callback)**
>
> ...
>
> You can provide multiple callbacks, and all are treated equally, and behave just like middleware, except that these callbacks may
>   invoke next('route') to bypass the remaining route callback(s). You
>   can use this mechanism to perform pre-conditions on a route then pass
>   control to subsequent routes when there is no reason to proceed with
>   the route matched.

This is how your authentication middlware function may look like:

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(/*check authentification*/) {
    return next();
  }

  res.send('auth failed');
}
```

On the other hand `passport.js` [provides a built-in function](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) that can be used as Express middleware.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

Authenticating requests is as simple as calling passport.authenticate() and specifying which strategy to employ. Strategies must be configured prior to using them in a route. Continue reading the chapter on [configuration](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I must have stumbled on the wrong version of the doc something, because I swear it was something like (path, handler)...